# How to get solution to make this determinant zero?

Tags: matlab, optimization, determinants

```
A = [A-x(1) B-x(2) C-x(3);D-x(4) E-x(5) F-x(6); G-x(7) H-x(8) I-x(9)]
```

I have to obtain `x(1)...x(9)` for `det(A) = 0`.

Comment: you have A(matrix) = [A - x(1) ....] This A inside is also the same matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a `3x3` matrix `A`

[image: <code>A</code> matrix]

its determinant is

[image: |A|]

therefore you need to solve `|A| = 0`. For your case we are given

[image: A - x]

The easiest solution for `x` so that `|A| = 0` is when

```
a - x(1) = 0
b - x(2) = 0
c - x(3) = 0
```

which leads to

```
x(1) = a
x(2) = b
x(3) = c
```

so

```
x = A
```

is the most trivial solution. There exists an infinite number of solutions to this problem, this is just one. You could choose another solution where

```
a - x(1) != 0
b - x(2) != 0
c - x(3) != 0
```

and then you would have to set

```
ei - fh = 0
di - fg = 0
dh - eg = 0
```

which would involve simultaneous equations.

---

I suggest before trying to code up a solution you work through one by hand like I've done here.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
But,
a - x(1) != 0
b - x(2) != 0
c - x(3) != 0
and
ei - fh != 0
di - fg != 0
dh - eg != 0

So I think, I have to use optimizat algorithm to minimize det(A)...

Comment: Your comment is unclear are you saying you can't choose `x = A`, if so that would have been some very important information to include in the original question.